# What notes template is this?

Tags: templates

Does anyone know where I can find the template for these gorgeous notes?

[image]

Comment: Reminds me somewhat (fatally) on the Legrand Orange Book (although not orange ;-))

Comment: If you have the book, contact the author or publisher.

Comment: In fact, I have been using this template! You can download this template from Overleaf website.